# mysql mod function return negative number

Tags: php, mysql

Great example for this issue is to calculate remaining days for birthday

I am using DateDiff(CURRDATE(),"Birthday column") function and receive days difference and than i need to do mod 365.

Mod 365 is for retrieving 364 if contact had birthday yesterday.

DateDiff(CURRDATE(),CURRDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)= -1 
MOD(-1,365) = -1

:\ WIRED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution for this issue

MOD(MOD(Negative,365)+365),365)

```
USE `test`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `get_user_contacts`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`get_user_contacts` (user_id INT(11),lim INT(11))
BEGIN

DECLARE is_user_exist INT(11);
SELECT count(*) INTO is_user_exist FROM users WHERE `users`.`id` = user_id;
    IF is_user_exist =1 THEN
        SELECT `contacts`.*,MOD(MOD(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),`contacts`.`birthday` + INTERVAL (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURDATE())-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `contacts`.`birthday`)) YEAR)*(-1),365)+365,365) AS DiffDate FROM  contacts
        LEFT JOIN contacts_users ON `contacts`.`id` = `contacts_users`.`contact_id`
        LEFT JOIN users ON `contacts_users`.`user_id`  = `users`.`id` LIMIT lim;
    ELSE
SELECT 404 as error_number,'User not found.' as message;

    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about "days til birthday", then 365 won't handle leap year correctly.

```
SELECT @bd := DATE('1992-02-02');  -- for testing previous day
SELECT @bd := DATE('1992-05-02');  -- for testing future day
SELECT DATEDIFF(@bd +
        INTERVAL (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(@bd)) +   -- Age or Age+1
             (DAYOFYEAR(@bd) < DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()))  -- +1 for earlier this year; 
        YEAR,
    CURDATE());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but, you were missed the main point, I didn't ask question, I just present mysql open issue and solution.